# axios request getting blocked | Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to hit an endpoint in my reactjs code using `axios` but the request is getting blocked and I am getting the following error in my console.

Please suggest how to overcome this

[image]

Below is my code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import axios from "axios"
export default function App()
{
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={fetchdata}>Click Me</button>
    </>
  )
}

function fetchdata()
{

  const axios = require('axios');
  
  // Make a request for a user with a given ID
  return axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api')
    .then(response => {
      // handle success
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
  })
}
```

Comment: its working fine

Comment: oh, strange, I don't know what's causing the error in my case.

Comment: remove this `const axios = require('axios');`

Comment: It is a very common cors issue, if you are using a Django server for example try to add the localhost to the accepted sources, if not try to use a cors extension like [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en][1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because https://randomuser.me expects request from secured origin using https protocol and localhost by default does not runs over https. If this is not satisfied it will be returned as a warning/error by your browser.

However, if you have generated React Project using `create-react-app` then you can add following script in your package.json:

`"proxy": "https://randomuser.me"`

Please refer document of [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) for more details.

Comment: I have added it in `package.json` and restarted npm but I am getting the same error again

Answer (score 2):

It's working fine, please check here

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-dust-yvotv?file=/src/App.js

sometimes this error coming because you started any plugin/extention of cors in your browser